# Why is android dependencies getting marked automatically after eclipse restarts

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to build an application using Google Maps API, and while creating the new project I've chosen `minSdkVersion="8"` and `targetSdkVersion="17"`. It's automatically generating appcompat_v7 in Eclipse and showing an exclamatory sign on the project.

Following the Android developer's site I've done the following to add the support library to the projects:

1. Downloaded the Android support library.
2. Imported the appcompat library folder to Eclipse from `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/`.
3. Deleted the `android-support-v4.jar` file and copied it from `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4`.
4. ***Build Path > Add to Build Path*** for both appcompat v7 and android-support-v4.
5. In appcompat library project selected ***Build Path > Configure Build Path > Order and Export*** tab.
6. Checked both the `android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` files and unchecked Android dependencies.

I've also done the same process for `google-play-services_lib`.

After that, when I am creating my own project for Google Maps, I've done the following:

1. Right-click in my project and from ***Properties > Android*** tab added the `google-play-services_lib` and `android-support-v7-appcompat` as library.
2. Deleted the `android-support-v4.jar` from lib folder in Eclipse and added it from `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4` and chose ***Build Path > Add to Build Path***.

After doing all these steps it works fine, no errors shown, but again when I restart Eclipse my project shows the error (the exclamatory sign), and also this same sign in `android-support-v7-appcompat` lib project. Also I can see that the android dependencies under ***Configure Build Path > Order and Export*** tab has been checked (which I have unchecked at the beginning when configuring the appcompat v7). If I uncheck it and delete the v4 and copy it again then the errors are gone.

Why do I have to do this every time? Am I doing anything wrong, or is there anything that needs to be done to solve it?

FYI, I have unchecked the automatically build options from project, too.